# How do I deserialize Objects from a file into a list?

Tags: java

I'm trying to deserialize flat Object(s) from a file, but get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class hausverwaltung.EigentumsWohnung cannot be cast to class java.util.List (hausverwaltung.EigentumsWohnung is in module hausverwaltung of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

This is my code:

```java
public List<Flat> getFlats() {
    List<Flat> flats = new ArrayList<Flat>();

    try {
        ObjectInputStream reader;
        reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        flats = (List<Flat>) reader.readObject();
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Deserialisation error: "+e);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    return flats;
}
```

This is the way how we learned it in class, but I somehow get this error.
I tried to find solutions all day and didn't find any... How can I fix this?

Comment: You are casting Flat to List<Flat>

Comment: To deserialize list of objects you need to serialize list of objects earlier, not single object.

Comment: thank you! I think now it works

Answer (score 0):

`reader.readObject` reads one object. In your case one `Flat`.

You are casting a single `Flat` to `List<Flat>` which is causing your exception.

To achieve your goal you should read the objects one by one and add them to a list, then return the list.

Comment: I have tried that, but then I get an EOFException..

Comment: Are you sure that the file is correct ?

Comment: @philimilli you need to check if the input has another entry first

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
flats= (Flat) reader.readObject();
```

It will work if there is one object per file.

**EDIT**: here's [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102996/how-to-read-a-list-of-list-of-objects-from-a-file-using-objectinputstream-in-jav) which is

Comment: But with that Im casting from Flat to List<Flat> that wont work

Comment: Please see the edit